# 'No callback function was given' error when using bcrypt-nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Trying to store encrypted passwords in a Postgres database using Bcrypt-nodejs and when we run the code or run our tests we get the error 'Unhandled rejection No callback function was given'.

We can't find any examples that work and wondered if anyone else had struggled with this and found solutions?

Here's the code in our model:

```js
'use strict';
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
 var User = sequelize.define('User', {
   first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
   last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
   email: DataTypes.STRING,
   password_digest: DataTypes.STRING,
   password: {
     type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
     allowNull: false,
     validate: {
       notEmpty: true
     }
   },
   password_confirmation: {
     type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL
   }
 }, {
   classMethods: {
     associate: function(models) {
       // associations can be defined here
     }
   }
 });
 var hasSecurePassword = function(user, options, callback) {
  if (user.password != user.password_confirmation) {
    throw new Error("Password confirmation doesn't match Password");
  }
  bcrypt.hash(user.get('password'), 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) { return callback(err); }
    user.set('password_digest', hash);
    return callback(null, options);
  });
 };

 User.beforeCreate(function(user, options, callback) {
  user.email = user.email.toLowerCase();
  if (user.password) {
    hasSecurePassword(user, options, callback);
  } else {
    return callback(null, options); }
 });
 return User;
};
```

Comment: Mind posting the error stack?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `bcrypt` and not `bcrypt-nodejs`.